# CodeIgniter - how to transfer array from controller to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote some register page. And i would like to create success page with success info about registration. 
This is my controller

```
function register(){
    $data['success']=0;
    $data['error']=0;
    if($_POST){

        $config=array(
            array(
                'field'=>'username',
                'label'=>'Login',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[64]|is_unique[users.username]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'email',
                'label'=>'Adres email',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'password',
                'label'=>'Hasło',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[16]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'password2',
                'label'=>'Potwierdź hasło',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|matches[password]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'namePTS',
                'label'=>'Imie i nazwisko',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|max_length[64]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'idPTS',
                'label'=>'ID postaci',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|integer|max_length[10]'
            )
        );
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data['error']=1;
            $data['errors']=validation_errors();
        } else {
            $data=array(
                'username'=>$_POST['username'],
                'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                'password'=>sha1($_POST['password']),
                'namePTS'=>$_POST['namePTS'],
                'idPTS'=>$_POST['idPTS']
            );

            $this->load->model('user');
            $userid=$this->user->create_user($data);
            if(!$userid){
                $data['success']=1;
                redirect(base_url().'users/success');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('startHeader');
    $this->load->view('register',$data);
    $this->load->view('startFooter');
}

function success(){
    $this->load->view('startHeader');
    $this->load->view('success',$data);
    $this->load->view('startFooter');
}
```

And this is sample of my view

```
<div class="login-form">
    <?php if($success==1){?>
        <!-- BEGIN ERROR BOX -->
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <p><b>Success!</b></p>
            Registration compleate!.
        </div>
        <!-- END ERROR BOX -->
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

As You can see when $this->user->create_user($data); didn't return errors

```
$data['success']=1;
redirect(base_url().'users/success');
```

And in view i have statment if success==1 display success box.
But i doesn't work correct. I have error like that in user/success page

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 99
```

and

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: success

Filename: views/success.php

Line Number: 16
```

How i can do that correct?

Comment: You must set default error value because it's only defined when you have errors

Answer (score 1):

view success page if succeed and don't make method for that.

```
 redirect(base_url().'users/success');
```

=>

```
$this->load->view('startHeader');
$this->load->view('success',$data);
$this->load->view('startFooter');
```

*PS:Use `$this->input->post('sth')` insteado of `$_POST['sth']`
and
Codeigniter suggests to use `password_hash()` perhaps by bcrypt instead of md5, sha, ...*

Comment: Thanks it works well. I have question. When i use $this->input->post('sth') istead $_POST['sth'] what is correct if statement?
if ($this->input->post()) ?

Comment: yeah to check if the request is post or not use `if ($this->input->post()) ` on the other hand you don't have to check if each of post fields are set or not. (`isset($this->input->post('sth')) `not needed anymore)

Comment: _FYI you can select the answer that helped you as best answer by clicking on the tik sign at the left of it_

Answer (score 0):

`$data['success']=0;` sets an index in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), but that array isn't yet defined; which is why you get these notices. Either create it first (using `$data = array();`; or combine it and write this instead:

```
$data = array('success' => 0, 'error' => 0);
```